# Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail returns 'BadRequest'

Tags: azure, powershell, invoke-command

I had a 'Bad Request' error while trying to use Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail on my Powershell script to get consumption reports of multiple Azure subscriptions, I looked on the internet and it seems like this issue has been going for a while now, it has to do with the PS API being outdated and the function working for specific legacy subscriptions only.
I tried a workaround to this issue by using the Invoke-RestMethod, yet It was no luck either, this is my script :

```
Connect-AzAccount

$subList = Get-AzSubscription
$startDate = "2022-04-01"
$endDate = "2022-04-30"

foreach($sub in $subList) {
    $url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$($sub.Id)/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2023-03-01-preview&`$filter=properties/UsageStart ge '$startDate' and properties/UsageEnd le '$endDate'"
    $accessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://management.azure.com).Token
    $headers = @{
        Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"
    }
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method GET -Headers $headers
    $response | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Reports\$($sub.Name).csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

and this is the error I got when I ran the script on MS Visual Code:

> Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"code":"InvalidResourceType","message":"The resource type
> 'UsageDetails' could not be found in the namespace
> 'Microsoft.Consumption' for api version '2023-03-01-preview'. The
> supported api-v ersions are
> '2017-06-30-preview,2017-11-30,2018-01-31,2018-03-31,2018-05-31,2018-06-30,2018-08-31,2018-10-01,2018-11-01-preview,2018-12-01-preview,2019-01-01,2019-04-01-preview,2019-05-01-preview,2019-05-01,2019-10-01,20
> 19-11-01,2021-01-01,2021-10-01,2023-03-01'."}} At
> C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive - xyz\Documents\VScode\thirdtry.ps1:13 char:17
>
> - ... $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method GET -Headers $headers ...
> - ```
>               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod],
>     WebException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
>     Export-Csv : Could not find a part of the path
>     'C:\Reports\jhon-abc-prd.csv'. At C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive -
>     xyz\Documents\VScode\thirdtry.ps1:14 char:17
> - ... $response | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Reports$($sub.Name).csv" -NoTypeInf ...
> - ```
>               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Export-Csv], DirectoryNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Answer (score 0):

As the error message point outs the api version `2023-03-01-preview` is not supported and also make sure whether the path `C:\Reports$($sub.Name).csv` is present in the local machine.

I recommend you to change the api version to any of the supported versions that were mentioned in the above shared error message.

```
The supported api-v ersions are '2017-06-30-preview,2017-11-30,2018-01-31,2018-03-31,2018-05-31,2018-06-30,2018-08-31,2018-10-01,2018-11-01-preview,2018-12-01-preview,2019-01-01,2019-04-01-preview,2019-05-01-preview,2019-05-01,2019-10-01,20 19-11-01,2021-01-01,2021-10-01,2023-03-01'
```

I have changed the api version to `2023-03-01` in $url in your above script and tested it in my local machine script got executed successfully and able to see the `.csv` file created in the provided path.

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]

If the path exists and your script is falling that unable to create `.csv` I would suggest you run the `Vscode` in admin mode and run the above script.

Comment: thank you for your reply, however it seems like the issue has to do with the subscription nature, I tried changing the API version to 2023-03-01 and then debugging the command, I had this error message: 

  "error": {
    "code": "400",
    "message": "Subscription scope usage is not supported for current api version. Please use api version after 2019-10-01 (Request ID: fb25aacc-a9d6-4fba...)
"
@VenkateshDodda

Comment: I tried running VScode in admin mode, I even tried Powershell ISE also in admin mode, and it didn't work. I found this article on Github that has the same issue and from the comments it looked like a Microsoft issue <link> https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/12561